# Aliasing singleton method in a module

Tags: ruby, module

I have a module called `Setup` and want to alias a method.

This is how it looks, but how it doesn't work:

```
module Setup
  def Setup::option_set?(option)
    #...
  end
  alias :option_set? :get_information
end
```

I guess it has to do with the `Setup::`-prefix. What to do?

Comment: Have you tried to lose the prefix?

Comment: then I cannot access the methods... learned this part by try and error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
module Setup
  class << self
    def option_set?(option)
      #...
    end
    alias :get_information :option_set? 
  end
end
```

Comment: You came first :)! Totally right! `option_set?` is a singleton method and to make an alias you have to do it inside a `class << self` definition!

Comment: no it shouldn't be a class, I do not need a class here, just a collection of methods under a general namespace...

Comment: saw Gerry's comment after writing my comment... this way I will alias it manually

Comment: What if I had to do it dynamically? Say I want the user to rename a method whose name is passed as a parameter?